# Does the dynamics of this Fund follow a GBM?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a Fund $F_t$ made of a bond ($B_t$) combined with an equity ($S_t$). $$F_t=S_t + B_t$$The dynamics are :
$ dB_t = r B_tdt$ and $dS_t=rS_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$ where $r$ and $\sigma$ are constant quantities. I would write the dynamics of the fund as follow
$$dF_t=dS_t+dB_t=rF_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$$
Looking at the result I would say it's not a GBM. I was expecting some know dynamics

Comment: It's not. The Brownian part of the dynamic is not a multiple of $F_t$.